# WooCommerce - Assign parent term when child term is set using Functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

TL:DR - Trying to assign parent category automatically to products in Woocommerce using functions.php where a product primary category is set as a child category. PS: apologies for formatting issues in this post. I can't quite see where I'm going wrong!

First time posting here. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440624/woocommerce-assign-parent-term-when-child-term-is-set) on Stack Overflow titled "WooCommerce - Assign parent term when child term is set"; I'm rather a novice when it comes to code but I'm not completely daft. I plugged in the code on this post in my functions.php file and absolutely nothing happens. That post is 9 years old though, I don't know if there's any updates that would prevent it from working now.

I found [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133627/assign-parent-category-to-all-posts-that-are-already-assigned-to-child-category) on Stack Exchange, this was seeking the same result but for WordPress posts, rather than products. I thought I had the solution because I was able to figure out how to change code on another function so that it assigned the title to the focused keyword in Rankmath SEO plugin so that it applied to products rather than posts. I got to work and then... nothing.

The code I'm working with can be found on the posts I've linked to but mainly, it is these:
First bit of code for Woocommerce from 9 years ago:

```
function set_product_parent_categories( $post_id ) {
    $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
        if( $term_id->parent > 0 ) {
            // Assign product to the parent category too.
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $term_id->parent, 'product_cat' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', __NAMESPACE__.'\\set_product_parent_categories', 10, 1 );
```

Second piece of code from Stack Exchange relating to posts:

```
$_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
function complete_parent_category( $term_id, $dep=array() ) {
    $category = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );
    $dep[ $category->term_id ] = $category->slug;
    if( $category->parent ) {
    $dep = complete_parent_category( $category->parent, $dep );
    }
    return $dep;
}
echo '<pre>';
while( $_query->have_posts() ) {
$_query->next_post();
echo '<br /><strong>'.$_query->post->post_title .'</strong> |>> ';
$cat_post = array();
$cats = get_the_category( $_query->post->ID );
if( count( $cats ) ) {
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $cat_post[ $cat->term_id ] = $cat->slug;
    if( $cat->parent == 0 ) continue; 
    $category_object = get_term( $cat, 'category' );
    $cat_post = complete_parent_category( $cat->parent, $cat_post );
    }
}
if( count( $cats ) == count( $cat_post ) ) return;
$data = array(
    'ID'           => $_query->post->ID,
    'post_category' => array_keys($cat_post),
);
wp_update_post( $data );
}

wp_reset_postdata();

exit();
```

The code I came up trying to make the second bit of code do the job of the first bit of code:

```
$_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
function complete_parent_category( $product_id, $dep=array() ) {
    $product_cat = get_term( $product_id, 'product_cat');
    $dep[ $product_cat->product_id ] = $product_cat->slug;
    if( $product_cat->parent ) {
    $dep = complete_parent_category( $product_cat->parent, $dep );
    }
    return $dep;
}
echo '<pre>';
while( $_query->have_posts() ) {
$_query->next_post();
echo '<br /><strong>'.$_query->post->post_title .'</strong> |>> ';
$product_cat = array();
$product_cat = get_the_category( $_query->post->ID );
if( count( $product_cat ) ) {
    foreach ($product_cat as $product_cat) {
    $cat_post[ $product_cat->term_id ] = $cat->slug;
    if( $product_cat->parent == 0 ) continue; 
    $category_object = get_term( $product_cat, 'category' );
    $cat_post = complete_parent_category( $product_cat->parent, $cat_post );
    }
}
if( count( $product_cat ) == count( $cat_post ) ) return;
$data = array(
    'ID'           => $_query->post->ID,
    'product_cat' => array_keys($cat_post),
);
wp_update_post( $data );
}

wp_reset_postdata();

exit();
```

And that just breaks the site and presents the entire website as a blank, white screen; I had to then jump into cpanel file manager and update the functions.php file there instead of on the WordPress backend. I've spent a good bit of time trying to make it work, and it either does nothing or completely shuts the site down (when you view-source, it just says `<pre>`, no `<head>` tags, no `<body>` tags... literally this is the entire source code:)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the first piece of code work on my site?

Just as an after thought, could the Rankmath code be conflicting with it? I'll past the Rankmath focus keyword code below for reference - I can't imagine it would interfere.

```
/**
* Function to automatically update the focus keyword with the product, posts and pages title, if no focus keyword is set
*/
function update_focus_keywords() {
    $products = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product' // Replace product with the name of your product type
    ));
    foreach ($products as $p) {
        // Checks if Rank Math keyword already exists and only updates if it doesn't have it
        $rank_math_keyword = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'rank_math_focus_keyword', true );
if ( ! $rank_math_keyword ){ 
        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword',strtolower(get_the_title($p->ID)));
        }
    }

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post' // Replace post with the name of your post type
    ));
    foreach($posts as $p){
        // Checks if Rank Math keyword already exists and only updates if it doesn't have it
        $rank_math_keyword = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'rank_math_focus_keyword', true );
if ( ! $rank_math_keyword ){ 
        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword',strtolower(get_the_title($p->ID)));
        }
    }
$pages = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page' // Replace product with the name of your product type
    ));
    foreach ($pages as $p) {
        // Checks if Rank Math keyword already exists and only updates if it doesn't have it
        $rank_math_keyword = get_post_meta( $p->ID, 'rank_math_focus_keyword', true );
if ( ! $rank_math_keyword ){ 
        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword',strtolower(get_the_title($p->ID)));
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'update_focus_keywords' );
```

Any help is really appreciated but please remember I'm really an absolute novice. I used common sense to improve the code I found for the Rankmath keywords - all I had to do was plug in "'post_type'      => 'product'" in place of 'post_type'       => 'posts'" - I've just become aware that by replacint "posts" for "product", the function isn't going to work for posts now. I've changed it to "'post_type'       => 'product','posts'" now, I expect that will take care of that. See, I'm not completely useless! But that's really the extent of my skills!

Comment: Not sure that formatting is 100% but think it is better than what you had. Need to use backticks around HTML if it is in plain text. e.g. `text \`<p>\` more text`.